# Can we say "Yes, you could" when someone asks "Could I wear jeans at work?"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, modal-verbs

Ok, according to my study

We can only use "**can**" & "**may**" to **give** permission in present

Eg: *I can / may wear jeans at work.*= *I have the permission to wear jeans at work.*

I am not sure if I can say "*I could wear jeans at work*" to express the same meaning.

However, we can use "**Can**", "**May**" & "**Could**" to **ask for** permission.

Eg: Can / may / could I wear jeans at work?

But if someone asks "**could I wear jeans at work?**" & we answer "**Yes, you could**", then it breaks the law that we can not use "**could**" to **give** permission

Can we say "**Yes, you could**" when someone asks "**Could I wear jeans at work?**"?

Comment: This question as asked makes no sense at all. It cites a "rule" for which no citation is given. The cited "rule" is unclear: it is not true that, for example, "may" may be used only to give permission in the present. "I may go to the gym tomorrow" is a perfectly valid sentence, but it is not granting permission and concerns the future rather than the past. I suspect what is meant is that **giving** permission in the present requires "may" or "can." But the question involves haing permission, and thus the rule, whatever it may be, is not pertinent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before addressing your questions specifically, let me digress briefly.

There have been lots of debates, here and elsewhere, on the use of **may** versus **can**.

While **may** is used in the sense of asking for permission, part of the problem with comparing it to **can** is that **can** has two different common senses.

> Can I do this?
>
> 1. Yes, you are allowed to do that.
> 2. Yes, you are able to do that.

In the one sense, **can** is also about asking permission. But in the other sense, it's about determining the *capability* of doing something.

---

Now for your question:

> Could I wear jeans to work?

Similarly to **can**, there is an ambiguous meaning—but it's slightly different.

> No, I can't let you do that.
>   Yes, you *could*. But it's against the rules.
>   Sure, that's not a problem.
>   Well, you *could*. But I'm not sure if you *should*.

Generally speaking, the final sense (one of *recommendation* or *suggestion*) isn't used with **may** or **can**—which are only about yes or no. But with **could**, questions and answers can have this additional nuance.

Also, we normally qualify the questions we ask when we use **could**:

> Could I wear jeans to work *if I wanted to*?

This means you're implicitly saying that you're able to wear jeans to work but what you're really after is if it's permissible to do so or not.

> Could I wear these skinny jeans to work if I went on a diet?

This means you're implicitly saying you have difficulty physically fitting into the jeans, and are asking not for permission but for the likelihood of changing that situation with certain behaviour.

---

> . . . it breaks the law that we can not use "could" to give permission . . .

There is no such "law" that I'm aware of, and there are certainly no guidelines of syntax or semantics against it.

> "May I be allowed in?"
>   "No, you need to wait at the end of the line."
>   "What if I gave you fifty dollars? Could I be allowed in then?"
>   "Why, yes, you could be."

As I mention, **could** is less of a black-and-white word than **may** or **can**, but it still has those meanings as part of it—especially if questions are qualified in order to make one of those meanings more explicit.

Also, while **may** and **can** are used to express something about the present, **could** is used to express something about the future (or the past when it's used in the negative).

---

**Update**: It's true that in *formal* English, there is guidance against using the word **could** for *giving* permission. In [a blog post](https://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2013/07/01/can-or-could/), Oxford Dictionaries says that "when giving (or refusing) permission, only *can* (or *can’t*) and *may* (or *may not*) are acceptable."

But idiomatically, in informal conversation, I believe it is something that *is* used and taken to be meant as a way of expressing permission in the right context.

Consider the following sets of dialogue:

> "*Could* I please take this pen?"
>   "Yes, you *could*."
>
> "*Could* I please take this pen?"
>   "Yes, you *may*."

The second may be the formally correct way of expressing permission, but the first seems at least as natural an exchange—if not more so because people have a tendency when they repeat something back to somebody to repeat it back just as it was originally said rather than to change something.

Comment: There is no source saying "could" can be used to give permission. Do you have a reference link?

Comment: A problem with your last example is that no permission was promised. The scene might continue with "But I gave you fifty bucks and you said that I could be allowed in!". "Yeah, I said you could be. I didn't say you **would** be. Now, beat it!"

Comment: @Mattias You're right. *Could* doesn't always mean *would*. But while I like making jokes out of that (as did Captain Kirk in at least one instance I can recall), most people normally do imply permission when they use that word.

Comment: @tom A quick search provided me with no such reference. You are correct that in *formal* English *could* is not used to give permission. But I believe it's often used in informal (spoken) English for that purpose. I've updated my answer to mention this specifically.

Comment: @JasonBassford, that is the link I need. "Could I borrow your pen?"==> "Yes, you could (borrow my pen)."==> "would imply that yes, if I had a pen, it would be possible for you to borrow it."